# SQL query - sync tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. `Auth` and `User`

Auth has the ff. columns (source) 18883 rows

```
id | username | password
```

User has the ff. columns (destination) 18868 rows

```
id | username | first name | last name | email
```

hmmm

```
auth.id = user.id
auth.username = user.username
```

Now for some reason the `User` table has rows where some username is missing.
What I want to do is make a script that looks for missing rows on `User` and insert the id and username from `Auth` and insert `first name`='fname', `last name`='lname', `email`='name@domain.com'.

So both tables will have the same number of rows and be in sync.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried manually looking for each row that is missing and do the insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unclear about what is missing . . . the id or the username or both.  Assuming the username specifies missing, the following query does what you want:

```
insert into user(id, uesrname, firstname, lsatname, email)
    select a.id, a.username. 'fname', lname', 'name@domain.com'
    from auth a left outer join
         user u
         on a.username = u.username
    where u.id is null
```

This assumes that username is not duplicated in the user table.

It seems strange that the column called "id" would have the same values in both tables.  You should revisit your data structure to see if this is really the case.  More often than not, "id" would be an auto-incremented primary key.

Comment: Both will actually be missing.

Comment: But is the key connecting the two tables a composite key or is one field sufficient as the key?

Comment: auth id is a key, but user id is not. its just get the id and username from auth. as for auth id autoincrements.

Comment: wierd, tried it on the live db. it says violation of primary key constaint `pK_user....`

Comment: its wierd its inserting even if id is in sync on both.